# Android WebView HTML/CSS layout works different from browser

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview

We have a hybrid app which load a HTML/CSS page in Android APP, when I debug in Mac Chrome, the style works well. But when I load the page in Android, the layout works vary from device to device.

How can I find a way to handle those different situation？

Sorry I can't even explain my question in detail, because I don't know where the key point is. It also be ok if you can give me some keywords to search about it.

#### HTML/CSS code:

```css
html {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.pic {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.pic .pic__image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2.22rem;
  height: 1.667rem;
  margin-left: 1.48rem;
  float: right;
}

.note {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2.22rem;
  height: 1.667rem;
  right: 0;
}

.icon {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Roboto-Regular;
  font-size: 0.27778rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.60);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.type-3 .icon__video {
  /*Video*/
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 0.91667rem;
  height: 0.5rem;
  line-height: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 .5em;
}

.type-3 .icon__video img {
  display: inline;
  max-width: 0.2rem;
  max-height: 0.2rem;
  line-height: 0.5rem;
}

.type-4 .icon__gif {
  /*Video*/
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 0.833rem;
  height: 0.833rem;
  line-height: 0.833rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="pic">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/500/300" alt="" class="pic__image">
  <div class="note type-4">
    <div class="icon icon__gif"> GIF </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="pic">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/500/300" alt="" class="pic__image">
  <div class="note type-3">
    <div class="icon icon__video">
      <img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,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">      00:11:57
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Here are some screenshot in different devices:

- In desktop Chrome: my expecting layout
  [image: In desktop Chrome]
- In Phone1 APP: the GIF div layout entirely wrong
  [image: Phone1]
- In Phone2 APP: the GIF text can't be vertical center
  [image]

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Upload your code.!

Comment: use this .type-4 .icon__gif{
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

Comment: Thanks! the GIF div works well by your code @veera

Comment: Does it only can use ps rather than rem? My root font would change in different screen. @veera

Comment: actually your code is correct, check your responsive style sheet.. @Soyaine

Comment: OK Thank you very much. @veera

Comment: @Soyaine I have experience that percentage alone not work in Webview. You need to answer a height in px or a width in px then you can say 100% to to the other one

Comment: Yeah, I picked the important css code here, in real code the picture with percentage is placed in a list. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Do you use any CSS libaries? Like bootstrap?

Comment: @Steven I use lib-flexible for respinsive style sheet, and jQuery for ajax. just those two. No pure CSS libaries.

Comment: How do you link to them? By CDN? Or local?

Comment: linked by CDN @Steven

Comment: Does your JQuery works and the responsive style sheet? Otherwise download them and link them local. Because I haven't find a methode to let the CDN works in android webview and also faster when you load local.